# How to resolve a flask app that is not able to locate HTML document in the templates folder resulting in an internal sever error

Tags: python, flask

This is the full error we receive when running the flask application in the browser.

"Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application."

I've done some research and have already attempted to link the folder with the
`app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='/templates')` assignment.

Here is my directory and debug logs. Any insight would be appreciated.

[Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Csj4O.png)

[Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cU3Xn.png)

Comment: In Linux-based OSs having a `/` before a folder name indicates that the folder is situated at the very top of the directory structure. Try adding a `.` before it, i. e. `template_folder='./templates')`.

Comment: You don't have '/' in your code, your code is   `app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates'`

Comment: Please post the relevant information like the samples of code and error tracebacks in textual form, so that others can more easily experiment with it to help you. Links, including links to images can one day become invalid and make your question unreadable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it `app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates')`

Comment: Oh my god. I can't believe I missed that. I spent 2 hours trying to figure out the issue. Thank you!

Comment: This is what his current code looks like now, in the screenshot (`app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates')`)

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs some changes. First of all, try using

```
render_template('prediction.html')
```

instead of

```
render_template('templates/prediction.html')
```

as Flasks already looks at templates folder (which in this case means that it will look for a folder 'templates' inside the folder 'templates')

If this doesn't work, try the same but when you declare the folder do it by:

```
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='/templates')
```

(with '/' before templates)
and not your current

```
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates')
```

If nothing of the above works, just the same solutions, without declaring template_folder at all, as by default Flask looks in the folder named 'templates'

Comment: Please reconsider the accepted answer. I don't think that the accepted answer resolved your issue, as your code already was `app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates')` already. If it resolved it, then your question must be corrected.